ggplot2 visualizes monthly data as daily data
I have a dummy data frame t. It contains monthly measurements of some Value for 3 groups. Note that group B has only one measurement.
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

t <- tibble(Group = c('A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C'),
            Month = c('2024-01-01', '2024-02-01', '2024-01-01', '2024-01-01', '2024-02-01', '2024-03-01'),
            Value = c(10, 10, 12, 9, 9, 12))

When I try to plot Value over Month faceted by Group...
t %>%
  mutate(Month = as.Date(Month, '%Y-%m-%d')) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Month, Value)) +
  geom_col() +
  facet_wrap(~Group)

I get an ugly chart. ggplot seems to interpret Month column as if it had daily frequency.
However, when I exclude group B (the only group with a single measurement)...
t %>%
  filter(Group != 'B') %>%
  mutate(Month = as.Date(Month, '%Y-%m-%d')) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Month, Value)) +
  geom_col() +
  facet_wrap(~Group)

The chart looks great! ggplot interprets Month column as having monthly frequency (as it does)
In general, this behavior happens when a faceted chart has at least one facet with a single observation. Then ggplot can not determine the proper frequency and assumes the smalles frequency for the whole chart.
I tried switching group names (perhaps, the order causes the problem) and converting string to date with lubridate library. Neither worked. I also tried converting Month column to factor. Then the plot looked great, but it lost the flexibility of Date format.
Is it intended behavior? Is there a way to explicitly set date frequency (e.g. to monthly)? I have ggplot2 3.5.1.

I've reverted to ggplot2 version 3.4.4 and it fixed the issue.

This is indeed a quirk in ggplot2 when handling date scales across facets with varying numbers of observations. ggplot tries to determine the best time scale for the entire plot, but when one facet has only a single data point, it sometimes defaults to interpreting the date at the smallest unit (daily) instead of the intended frequency (monthly).
To get around this, you can set the breaks for the x-axis explicitly to monthly, which helps ggplot consistently interpret the date scale as monthly across facets. Here’s how you can modify your code to enforce monthly breaks:
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

t <- tibble(
  Group = c('A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C'),
  Month = c('2024-01-01', '2024-02-01', '2024-01-01', '2024-01-01', '2024-02-01', '2024-03-01'),
  Value = c(10, 10, 12, 9, 9, 12)
)

t %>%
  mutate(Month = as.Date(Month, '%Y-%m-%d')) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Month, Value)) +
  geom_col() +
  facet_wrap(~Group) +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month", date_labels = "%Y-%m")  # Enforce monthly breaks

Here’s what this does:

scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month", date_labels = "%Y-%m") specifies that the x-axis should show ticks every month, regardless of the number of observations within each facet.

This should give you the intended monthly frequency interpretation while retaining the flexibility of the Date format.

It didn't help in my case

probably because you didn't explicitly set the width od the bars. ALSO set geom_col(width = 26) +
